# How to display loading image on entire record page instead only on the inline VF page?

Tags: visualforce, detail-page

I have a inline visualforce page in the Opportunity Detail page. Data in the visualforce page is related to opportunity, whenever I update the data in the VF page, I am showing the loading image , after which I am refreshing the entire detail page. As of now loading image is shown only on vf page.Instead I want to display the loading image on the entire detail page.

I even tried using jQuery, I am able to achieve displaying of loading image only on inline vf page but couldn't accomplish on entire detail page.

In the below screen shot you can find the loading image displayed over inline vf page

Please suggest me an idea to implement the same.
[image: Screen shot of inline vf page with loading image]

Answer (score 0):

In Lex you can achieve it by creating a lightning data service component which may detect any changes to detail page record and then you can fire a lightning spinner whenever the record loads or some changes you do to the record.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to achieve this in Classic version of my app